# ANTLR4 - Parse subset of a language (e.g. just query statements)

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, u-sql

I'm trying to figure out how I can best parse just a subset of a given language with ANTLR. For example, say I'm looking to parse [U-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/). Really, I'm only interested in parsing certain parts of the language, such as [query statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/query-statements-and-expressions). I couldn't be bothered with parsing the many other features of the language. My current approach has been to design my lexer / parser grammar as follows:

```
// ...

statement
    :    queryStatement
    |    undefinedStatement
    ;

// ...

undefinedStatement
    :    (.)+?
    ;

// ...

UndefinedToken
    :    (.)+?
    ;
```

The gist is, I add a fall-back parser rule and lexer rule for undefined structures and tokens. I imagine later, when I go to walk the parse tree, I can simply ignore the undefined statements in the tree, and focus on the statements I'm interested in.

This seems like it would work, but is this an optimal strategy? Are there more elegant options available? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing a subpart of a grammar is super easy. Usually you have a top level rule which you call to parse the full input with the entire grammar.

For the subpart use the function that parses only a subrule like:

```
const expression = parser.statement();
```

I use this approach frequently when I want to parse stored procedures or data types only.

Keep in mind however, that subrules usually are not termined with the EOF token (as the top level rule should be). This will cause no syntax error if more than the subelement is in the token stream (the parser just stops when the subrule has matched completely). If that's a problem for you then add a copy of the subrule you wanna parse, give it a dedicated name and end it with EOF, like this:

```
dataTypeDefinition: // For external use only. Don't reference this in the normal grammar.
    dataType EOF
;

dataType: // type in sql_yacc.yy
    type = (
...
```

Check the [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L3219) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This general idea -- to parse the interesting bits of an input and ignore the sea of surrounding tokens -- is usually called "island parsing". There's an example of an island parser in the ANTLR reference book, although I don't know if it is directly applicable.

The tricky part of island parsing is getting the island boundaries right. If you miss a boundary, or recognise as a boundary something which isn't, then your parse will fail disastrously. So you need to understand the input at least well enough to be able to detect where the islands are. In your example, that might mean recognising a `SELECT` statement, for example. However, you cannot blindly recognise the string of letters `SELECT` because that string might appear inside a string constant or a comment or some other context in which it was never intended to be recognised as a token at all.

I suspect that if you are going to parse queries, you'll basically need to be able to recognise any token. So it's not going to be sea of uninspected input characters. You can view it as a sea of recognised but unparsed tokens. In that case, it should be reasonably safe to parse a non-query statement as a keyword followed by arbitrary tokens other than `;` and ending with a `;`. (But you might need to recognise nested blocks; I don't really know what the possibilities are.)